# Delete all rows from account, except most recent eleven

Tags: mysql, sql

Upon submitting a review, I'm trying to run a query that deletes all rows with matching account number, except the eleven most recent. My table consists of "account","stamp"(datetime), and "reviews".

The account number is passed in the variable `$account`.

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE account=?
AND stamp NOT IN (SELECT stamp FROM table ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 11)
```

Not sure what is wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `delete` and `join`:

```
delete t
    from table t left join
         (select t.*
          from table t
          where account = ?
          order by stamp desc
          limit 11
         ) tt
         on t.account = tt.account and t.stamp = tt.stamp
    where t.account = ? and tt.account is null;
```

Comment: I used the answer from @juergen d, but it appears your solution will work as well, hence the up vote:)

Comment: @bcintegrity . . . The two do not do the same thing.  This version keeps 11 records with the account.  Juergen's version only keeps version that are in the 11 most recent times stamps *over all the data*.  Keeping 11 versions seemed to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I see what you mean. I added the `WHERE account='$account'` statement into the subquery of Juergen's example, which is working properly. For some reason, `JOINS` scare me. lol :)